# convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt{n}]}}{n}$ where $[a]$ means floor function of $a$

Tags: convergence-divergence, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have a problem with solving the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt{n}]}}{n}$ where $[a]$ means floor function of $a$. I've already made the first thep and rewrote it with the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n}\sum_{k=n^2}^{(n+1)^2-1}\frac{1}{k}$, which converges if and only if the previous one converges. Now I want to use Leibniz criterion, but I cannot prove that the second sum in the previous expression is monotonic. Does anyone know how to do it?
(I cannot use Riemann integral, we haven't defined it yet)

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535784/how-find-series-sum-n-1-infty-dfrac-1-sqrtmnna), with a broad interpretation of duplicate it would count as one.

Comment: I would guess that you would have some luck relating $a_n=\sum_{k=n^2}^{(n+1)^2-1}\frac{1}{k}$ to the integral of $\frac{1}{n}$ through left and right Riemann sums.  Getting it so that $a_n$ > some definite integral > some other integral > $a_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us recall the definition of the [hamronic numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html) $$\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k}=H_{N}
 $$ hence $$S=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left\lfloor \sqrt{n}\right\rfloor }}{n}=-1+\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left\lfloor \sqrt{n}\right\rfloor }}{n}
 $$ $$=-1+\sum_{n\geq2}\left(-1\right)^{n}\left(H_{\left(n+1\right)^{2}-1}-H_{n^{2}-1}\right)
 $$and using $$H_{n}=\log\left(n\right)+\gamma+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
 $$ we get $$S=-1+\sum_{n\geq2}\left(-1\right)^{n}\log\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{2}-1}{n^{2}-1}\right)+O\left(1\right)
 $$ $$=-1+\sum_{n\geq2}\left(-1\right)^{n}\log\left(\frac{n\left(n+2\right)}{n^{2}-1}\right)+O\left(1\right)$$ and so we have the convergence for the Leibniz' criterion.