# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt n]}}{n}$ is converges where $[x]$ is the largest integer is less than or equal to x.

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt n]}}{n}$ converges where $[x]$ is the largest integer that is less than or equal to x.

Suggestion: Use the inequality $\frac{1}{l+1}< \int_{l}^{l+1} \frac{1}{x}dx <\frac{1}{l}$.

I solved this question with Dirichlet test.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Let $a_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$. It is monotonically decreasing and approaches to zero.

and $b_{n}=(-1)^{[\sqrt n]}$ and the partial sum is bounded .

By the given DT, it $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}{b_{n}$ is convergent.

Can I solve this question by this approach?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535784/how-find-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1-sqrtmnna

Answer (score 4):

You can apply Dirichlet's test but not to $a_n= \frac1n,b_n = (-1)^{[\sqrt n]}$ (as $\sum_{n\le x}(-1)^{[\sqrt n]}$ is not bounded), look instead at $a_n = \frac1{n^{1/3}}, b_n=\frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt n]}}{n^{2/3}}$ so that the boundedness of $\sum_{n\le x} b_n$ is obvious.

Comment: Please can you clarify the boundedness here?

Comment: @kapil: bounded above and below by given constants.

Comment: However, the boundedness of $\sum\limits_{k\le n}\frac{(-1)^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{k}\right\rfloor}}{k^{2/3}}$ is not much more obvious than the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your sum can be written as
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\sum_{k=n^2}^{n^2+2n}\frac1k\tag1
$$
Furthermore, it is simple to see that
$$
\sum_{k=n^2}^{n^2+2n}\frac1k=\frac2n+O\!\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\tag2
$$
Thus, the sum converges since the alternating harmonic series converges and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$ converges absolutely.