# Convergence test of $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{\left \lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\right \rfloor}}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

As the title states, I'm trying to prove that the series
$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{\left \lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\right \rfloor}}{n}$ is not convergent.

I managed to bring it down to:

$ S = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \left( \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^2+1} + \ldots + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2-1} \right) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n b_n$,

but I cannot prove that $b_n$ is monotonically decreasing/increasing.

Comment: Not that it makes a difference for whether the series converges, but in the title you use the ceiling, in the body the floor. It would be better to have title and body match.

Comment: @DanielFischer My bad. I have edited the title. Thanks.

Comment: As a sort of update, plotting the signals seems to show it converging to value between -1.3 and -1.28.

Comment: If that helps, $\frac{2n+1}{n^2+2n}<b_n<\frac{2n+1}{n^2}$, so $b_n=\frac2n+O(\frac1{n^2})$.

Comment: It does converge (I don't know what to). I'm pretty sure this question has been asked here before, I'm looking for a duplicate.

Comment: [A more general result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535784/how-find-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1-sqrtmnna)

Comment: It converges, it's not really tricky but of course, direct use of the test for alternative series is not a nice way to it.  For this one, you can divide the inner sum in two parts . ie $$ \sum = \dfrac{2n+1}{n^2} + \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \dfrac{1}{n^2+k}-\frac{1}{n^2} $$.
The sum of second part converges absolutely, the sum of the first converges by the test of alternative series.